# pgfplots: "x stick" style

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to reproduce the following example.
The xbar and ybar options are not really what I am looking for since I am only interested in having horizontal lines as markers of points.

Is there any way to do that in pgfplots ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the length of the horizontal bars does not carry additional information, but is merely aesthetic. You can use the option `mark=-` to get horizontal lines, the thickness can be controlled with `line width`, the "radius" (i.e. half the length) can be set with `mark size`.

You didn't specifically ask for it, but since you said you're trying to reproduce the example, I also added symbolic x coordinates and and formatted the x tick labels to show the letter in brackets:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[only marks,
  every axis plot post/.style={mark=-,ultra thick,mark size=4pt},
  symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d},
  xtick={a,b,c,d},
  xticklabel={(\tick)}]
\addplot +[red] coordinates {
  (a,-3.8)
  (b,-4)
  (c,-4)
  (d,-1.9)};
\addplot +[blue] coordinates {
  (a,-8.25)
  (b,-8.1)
  (c,-8.1)
  (d,-6.2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: horizontal bars as markers]

Comment: I had tried the mark=- option but didn't thought of combining it with mark size to increase the length ! Anyway, that's exactly waht I was looking for. Many thanks for your prompt answer and the detailed explanation.

Comment: I actually still have one question: when using the `nodes near coords` option to get values near markers, if two markers are too close, nodes are overlapping (set (a,-3.8) and (a,-3.75) for instance). Is it possible to specifically shift some of these automatically-generated nodes ? Thanks !

Comment: @FFF: There's no easy way to move individual markers. What I would probably do in your case is to use the option `nodes near coords align=south` option for the upper plot and `nodes near coords align=north` for the lower plot. However, this really only makes sense if one of the plots is always higher than the other. If you do need a way to move individual markers, you should probably ask a new question. Also, if you consider the current question about the horizontal markers to be answered, you should accept the answer by clicking the green tick mark.

Comment: many thanks. Using something like `nodes near coords align={anchor=south}` was enough in my case to solve the overlapping problem.